# Is there a way to use Kotlin lambda to create java.util.funtion.Function?

Tags: java, function, kotlin, lambda

I tried to write the following code:

```
val s: Function<String, String> = { s -> s + s }
```

It compiles with the following error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is (???) -> [Error type: Return type for function cannot be resolved] but Function<String, String> was expected

Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
```

What is the proper way to assign `Kotlin` lambda to `Java` function?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Function<String, String>`, full example:

```
import java.util.function.Function

fun main() {
    val s: Function<String, String> = Function { s -> s + s }
    val result = s.apply("Kotlin")
    println(result) // KotlinKotlin
}
```